# Does rest_framework coreapi not support PUT / PATCH?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, core-api

I'm wanting to use the [Python Client Library](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/api-clients/#python-client-library), but having no end of pain getting PUT/PATCH to work. Whenever I try using update / partial_update, the URL param isn't interpolated from the dictionary, and the server returns a 404.

```
[06-Jun-2017 12:30:05] WARNING [django.server:124] "PUT /api/accounts/networks/%7Bcid%7D/ HTTP/1.1" 404 23
```

Which clearly shows that the {cid} param was never replaced with the actual value. Which brings me to the TL/DR version of my question, does CoreAPI not support PUT / PATCH?

The PUT / PATCH options are correctly setup, according to this info:

```
GET /api/accounts/networks/2892c424-3a86-16bb-8b60-12a79900e90c/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
```

---

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/networks/2892c424-3a86-16bb-8b60-12a79900e8fb/",
    "created": "2016-04-16T19:35:02.169898Z",
    "modified": "2017-05-30T17:25:29.768740Z",
    "cid": "2892c424-3a86-16bb-8b60-12a79900e8fb",
    "name": "10.0.0.0/8",
    "comments": "Local Area Network - 10.x",
    "builtin": true
}
```

Now that I've blown most of a morning trying to make this work, I realize that there's [no documentation example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/api-clients/#python-client-library) showing update / partial update.

So I thought I'd try using `coreapi-cli` instead, but I have the same problem.

```
coreapi action networks partial_update --param cid='2892c424-3a86-16bb-8b60-12a79900e8fb' --param comments='this is WAAAY too hard'
<Error: 404 Not Found>
    detail: "Not found."
```

Django's logline shows that the URL param was never substituted from the 'cid' param provided:

```
[06-Jun-2017 13:07:01] WARNING [django.server:124] "PUT /api/accounts/networks/%7Bcid%7D/ HTTP/1.1" 404 23
```

I can use override params to force the URL, and this now updates as anticipated.

```
client.action(['networks', 'partial_update'],
          params={'comments': 'this is WAAAY too hard', 'cid': '2892c424-3a86-16bb-8b60-12a79900e8fb'},
          overrides={'url': 'http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/networks/2892c424-3a86-16bb-8b60-12a79900e8fb/'},
          )
```

But that feels haaacky, and should be utterly unnecessary. So...

1. Is this a bug?
2. Have I gotten the function signature wrong?
3. Does CoreAPI not support PUT / PATCH methods?

## Edit

Here's the viewset

```
class LCModelViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     GenericViewSet):
    """
    Base ModelViewSet
    """
    lookup_field = 'cid'



class NetworksViewSet(LCModelViewSet):
    queryset = Networks.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NetworksSerializer
    filter_class = NetworksFilter
```

and the Router

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'accounts/networks', av.NetworksViewSet, base_name='api-networks')
```

and the output of router.routes

```
[Route(url='^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$', mapping={'get': 'list', 'post': 'create'}, name='{basename}-list', initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}),
 DynamicListRoute(url='^{prefix}/{methodname}{trailing_slash}$', name='{basename}-{methodnamehyphen}', initkwargs={}),
 Route(url='^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$', mapping={'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update', 'patch': 'partial_update', 'delete': 'destroy'}, name='{basename}-detail', initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}),
 DynamicDetailRoute(url='^{prefix}/{lookup}/{methodname}{trailing_slash}$', name='{basename}-{methodnamehyphen}', initkwargs={})]
```

## Edit #2

At hurturk's suggestion, I reduced everything to defaults - `views.ModelViewset` and `serializers.ModelSerializer`, and put the `lookup_field` on the `NetworksViewSet`. Still same problem.

Then I removed the custom lookup field and just tried using the default `id` field (`cid` is not the PK), and VOILA, PUT/PATCH then worked - URL generated correctly! So, I wondered if for some reason it's a UUID-related issue.

Since `name` is a unique field, I set `lookup_field = name`. The same behavior as UUID. GET/POST methods work. PUT/PATCH don't `"PATCH /api/accounts/networks/%7Bname%7D/ HTTP/1.1" 404 23`.

So it seems to come to this, that when the `lookup_field` is the PK, then PUT/PATCH url is generated correctly. When `lookup_field` is some other field, then the URL `lookup_field` placeholder is never interpolated.

I don't know what to do. CID is a must-have requirement...

Comment: How does your view looks like? CoreAPI fetches schema provided by DRF first.

Comment: Looks like a bug with CoreAPI as it is  param safe already. Two more questions, where do you define your `lookup_field`? Just in case, could you comment out the filter and try again? You can also remove quotes from `cid`, that also works.

Comment: I'd simplified the viewset in this ticket, and forgot that that the edit removed the lookup_field declaration from the ticket code. Now edited the question, and showing the viewset class hierarchy. I'm not following you about "remove the quotes from `cid`. Where should that be done?

Comment: Oh I meant that for `coreapi-cli` but shouldn't make much difference. I still believe that is a bug, your code and calls look perfect to me. You can remove the inherited class, move `lookup_field` in `NetworksViewSet` and let it extend from `viewsets.ModelViewSet` try again before reporting this (to prove minimal example doesn't work).

Comment: I have tested your model with `python 3.4.3`, `coreapi 2.3.1`, `coreapi-cli 1.0.6`, `django 1.11`, `djangorestframework 3.6.2`, works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and for the work you went to. Updated the question with Edit #2.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the issue. :-)  `cid` must be set to readonly, and then the URL for PUT/PATCH is correctly formed.

Why must a `lookup_field` be readonly? If it's incorrect and unworkable to have a `lookup_field` be writable, an error message would be very helpful, instead of the current behavior.

## Edit

Well **thank you**, @hurkurk! I didn't notice your [PR](https://github.com/core-api/python-client/pull/138/commits)! That does fix my problem, at least when the `cid` doesn't need to be edited. It really would be great to have the path param specified separately from the request data, so that the `lookup_field` value could be changed on PUT/PATCH. But that's another discussion.

Comment: That sounds great! Readonly probably eliminates the confusion between path vs data but I think bug is still there. I will wait to see when project maintainer gives it a direction because this is also the discussion in restful design whether PUT/PATCH should rename the resource or not while that is allowed in DRF with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a bug with CoreAPI http transport as it is assuming all field names in schema are distinct. I have provided a [PR](https://github.com/core-api/python-client/pull/138) to fix it but this might need further design considerations by the project owner.

As you also mentioned, making lookup field read-only is an alternative solution to the problem because that would cause it to appear only once in the field analysis.